# Update Activity after login

Tags: java, android

I have my main activity with GridView layout with 12 elements for page. The elements are ImageButton.
When user start the app, the app show some default ImageButton.

My problem is: When the user do the login i have another list of ImageButton to add, so i want to refresh the main activity to show all ImageButton.

some code in the MainActivity:

```
//Default services
String mServices[] = {"1","2", "3", "4", "5", "6","7",
            "8","9","10"};

    ArrayList<String> mArrayServices = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < mServices.length; i++) {
            mArrayServices.add(i, mServices[i]);
        }


        Iterator<String> mIterator = mArrayServices.iterator();
        List<GridFragment> mGridFragments = new ArrayList<GridFragment>();
        mIterator = mArrayServices.iterator();

        int i = 0;
  while (mIterator.hasNext()) {
            ArrayList<GridItems> itmLst = new ArrayList<GridItems>();

            GridItems itm = new GridItems(0, mIterator.next());
            itmLst.add(itm);
            i = i + 1;

            if (mIterator.hasNext()) {
                GridItems itm1 = new GridItems(1, mIterator.next());
                itmLst.add(itm1);
                i = i + 1;
            }

            if (mIterator.hasNext()) {
                GridItems itm2 = new GridItems(2, mIterator.next());
                itmLst.add(itm2);
                i = i + 1;
            }

            if (mIterator.hasNext()) {
                GridItems itm3 = new GridItems(3, mIterator.next());
                itmLst.add(itm3);
                i = i + 1;
            }

            if (mIterator.hasNext()) {
                GridItems itm4 = new GridItems(4, mIterator.next());
                itmLst.add(itm4);
                i = i + 1;
            }

            if (mIterator.hasNext()) {
                GridItems itm4 = new GridItems(5, mIterator.next());
                itmLst.add(itm4);
                i = i + 1;
            }
            if (mIterator.hasNext()) {
                GridItems itm4 = new GridItems(6, mIterator.next());
                itmLst.add(itm4);
                i = i + 1;
            }
            if (mIterator.hasNext()) {
                GridItems itm4 = new GridItems(7, mIterator.next());
                itmLst.add(itm4);
                i = i + 1;
            }
            if (mIterator.hasNext()) {
                GridItems itm4 = new GridItems(8, mIterator.next());
                itmLst.add(itm4);
                i = i + 1;
            }
            if (mIterator.hasNext()) {
                GridItems itm4 = new GridItems(9, mIterator.next());
                itmLst.add(itm4);
                i = i + 1;
            }

            if (mIterator.hasNext()) {
                GridItems itm4 = new GridItems(10, mIterator.next());
                itmLst.add(itm4);
                i = i + 1;
            }
            if (mIterator.hasNext()) {
                GridItems itm4 = new GridItems(11, mIterator.next());
                itmLst.add(itm4);
                i = i + 1;
            }




            GridItems[] gp = {};
            GridItems[] gridPage = itmLst.toArray(gp);
            mGridFragments.add(new GridFragment(gridPage, MainActivity.this));
        }
        }

        mPageAd = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), mGridFragments);
        mAwesomePager.setAdapter(mPageAd);
```

The login is in the other Activity, and after that mServices can change.

For example:

1. User open the app and MainActivity contains 10 elements.
2. User do the login and MainActivity contains 15 elements.
3. User do the logout and MainActivity contains 10 elements.
   ...

Now I'm not sure how I can proceed...i use Otto library?..or another library? or what?

Comment: Does any events occur when use login or logout?

Comment: hmm simply put all button at first time with out login or with login make same screen and check for if user  have loged in then set visibility of extra button visible else gone

Comment: the ImageButtons after login are created by which condition? Are differents for each user? The user can add or remove theese ImageButtons? A user has the same ImageButtons every time he connected to app? Btw you could use several ways.. You could use a sqLite to save the buttons for each user or the sharedpreferences.

Comment: @mr.icetea when the user login the variable String mServices change from 10 elements to 15 elements

Comment: @End.Game yes the ImageButton is possible difference for each user. The user can't remove this button. And yes all user have this list of 10 elements always, but after login can change this list.

Comment: Can you show us your code where you're logging in? Also, is the `ImageButton` inside `GridView` which is to be shown if logged in?

Comment: You can use EventBus (https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) to post an event when the login is successful so that you can refresh your adapter attached to the GridView. You can do the same when user logout successfully.

Comment: If you want create something like that i suggest to use a database with a user table. By an id you can "controll" the buttons in the view to each user connected. For example; when a user login you will show the buttons only for that user by id. This is the way to customize the app.. The other solution is something static like @andrewww solution

Comment: @FrancescoDonzello EventBus is similar to Otto library?

Comment: Yes but more efficient (read this: https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus/blob/master/COMPARISON.md)

Answer (score 0):

Just Hide and show your extra 5 elements like this

```
    imageButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    and
    imageButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Better solution is use custom dialog with spread over full screen and does behave exactly like your login screen when login is successful then there is one callback method where you can does as you said

User open the app and MainActivity contains 10 elements.
User do the login and MainActivity contains 15 elements.
User do the logout and MainActivity contains 10 elements. ...

I think this approach will help you best of luck!!!!